# How to compare dates in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, date-comparison

I have a date stored in backend (e.g. '2016-09-29') and I wish to compare that date with lastModified date from S3 object (accessible by #[payload.getLastModified()]) . How do I form the MEL for date comparison in Mule ESB? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Mule MEL as described here

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-expression-language-date-and-time-functions#compare

Or use dataweave for comparison `(payload.lastModified as :date - payload.date as :date).months` this will give you the difference in months.

Hope this helps